# Flutter app run not work after change compileSdkVersion

Tags: android, flutter, build, build.gradle

I changed my file `build.gradle`

**From:**

```
compileSdkVersion 29
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 29
```

**To:**

```
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 18
targetSdkVersion 29
```

Then get error with message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     D:\Development\Projects\Dart\Flutter\tires\build\location\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-17:56: AAPT: error: attribute android:foregroundServiceType not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        23,1s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility. 
Building plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                    1,1s

D:\Development\Packages\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\embedding\engine\plugins\lifecycle\FlutterLifecycleAdapter.java:8: error: package androidx.lifecycle does not exist
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
                         ^
D:\Development\Packages\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\embedding\engine\plugins\lifecycle\FlutterLifecycleAdapter.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
  public static Lifecycle getActivityLifecycle(
                ^
  symbol:   class Lifecycle
  location: class FlutterLifecycleAdapter
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s


Exception: The plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle could not be built due to the issue above.
```

Comment: you need to set both `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` with same version

Comment: tried but get some error @ShubhamNarkhede

Answer (score 0):

can you try this way.

below that: android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 29

  defaultconfig{
   minSdkVersion:21
   targetSdkVersion 29
```

below that: android/build.gradle

```
 afterEvaluate {project ->

       if (project.hasProperty("android") && 
   project.property("android").compileSdkVersion.equals("android-R")) {

        android {

            compileSdkVersion 30

        }

    }
```

Comment: In my case works `compileSdkVersion 29 minSdkVersion 16 targetSdkVersion 29` but I need to `compileSdkVersion 28` and `minSdkVersion 18`

Comment: Your AndroidManifes.xml will not work because you are using existing minsdkVersion: 18 Api. You need to uninstall the APIs you use or use compatible minsdkVersion.

Comment: But I have in my pc flutter project which use compileSdkVersion 28 minSdkVersion 16 which runs succesfully. In this project doesn't work

Comment: As I said, the apis in the manifest.xml library used in that prode are different from yours. There are different APIs added there later. not working at minsdkversion: 18 on them. that's the whole reason.

Comment: What I must to do for fix error or it's impossible?

Comment: In `minSdkVersion 16` and `compileSdkVersion 30` also works

Comment: Do flutter clean first. then update compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion then reload. This is the idea that comes to my mind, man